# Mapping sometimes works but sometimes not

Tags: key-bindings

What I tried:

```
 :nnoremap <C-w>n <Enter>
```

Expected result:

- When pressing <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd>, just an <kbd>Enter</kbd> is simulated rather than horizontally splitting a window.

Actual result:

- The mapping sometimes works but sometimes not.

What I noticed:

- When lhs of `:map` is of the form `<C-X>Y` where `X` and `Y` are arbitrary characteres, mapping works only when you press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> and then **rapidly** press <kbd>Y</kbd>. If there is a delay (maybe hundreds milliseconds or so) before pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>, mapping does not work and original key-binding is used. By "original key-binding", I mean the un-mapped version of <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>, not just <kbd>Y</kbd>. So it seems this strange behavior doesn't come from time-out of <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>. (If so, it would be natural that un-mapped version of **just** <kbd>Y</kbd> is simulated.)

Environment:

```
~ $ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 15 2020 13:52:40)
Included patches: 1-259
```

How can I map to Ctrl+w n? Or does the behavior natural?

Comment: Try `set notimeout` and check it it would work for you. (It did for me)

Comment: @MaximKim It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @MaximKim worth an answer; the intricacies and interactions of the various timeout options can be confusing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I wouldn't be able to explain what are the drawbacks of using or not using this settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, the breakdown on mappings and "timing out":

```
'timeout'       boolean (default on)
'ttimeout'      boolean (default off, set in |defaults.vim|)
    These two options together determine the behavior when part of a
    mapped key sequence or keyboard code has been received:

    'timeout'    'ttimeout'     action
       off      off             do not time out
       on       on or off       time out on :mappings and key codes
       off      on              time out on key codes

    [snipped]
```

Essentially, by default, vim will time out on `:map`ped sequences and special key codes (like the `<Esc>.` that is the equivalent of pressing `<A-.>`).

You can control the length of said timeout with `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`:

```
'timeoutlen'    number  (default 1000)
'ttimeoutlen'   number  (default -1, set to 100 in |defaults.vim|)
    The time in milliseconds that is waited for a key code or mapped key
    sequence to complete.  Also used for CTRL-\ CTRL-N and CTRL-\ CTRL-G
    when part of a command has been typed.
    Normally only 'timeoutlen' is used and 'ttimeoutlen' is -1.  When a
    different timeout value for key codes is desired set 'ttimeoutlen' to
    a non-negative number.

        ttimeoutlen mapping delay      key code delay
           < 0      'timeoutlen'       'timeoutlen'
          >= 0      'timeoutlen'       'ttimeoutlen'

    The timeout only happens when the 'timeout' and 'ttimeout' options
    tell so.  A useful setting would be
        :set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
    (time out on mapping after three seconds, time out on key codes after
    a tenth of a second).
```

So it sounds like by default, you should get at least 1 second for mappings and key-codes alike, unless you're using the line from `defaults.vim` such that key-codes only get 100s.

---

### Options for a solution

1. Disable timeouts entirely (`set notimeout nottimeout`)—personally, I don't recommend this, but YMMV.
2. Enable timeouts on mappings as longer, and keycodes as shorter (`set timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100`)—this is what I've been using and I've not had any issues. Your mapping works for me with this setup.

---

### Understanding where the issue might be

Try running

```
verbose set timeout? ttimeout? timeoutlen? ttimeoutlen?
```

The results should be informative.

Comment: Thank you. In `.vimrc`, I set `set timeoutlen=300`, and this is the cause. I didn't know one can set different delays for mappings and key codes. I'll additionally set `ttimeoutlen` as you recommend.